# subset array with Fortran given a condition?

Tags: fortran

Suppose I have an array A(n,m). Is it possible to subset that array in Fortran to create a new array? For example,

```
A = 11   22   43   55
    15   56   65   63
    54   56   32   78
```

I want to create an array B with m-1 columns and the rows that satisfies A(:,2) .eq. 56

So B should be:

```
B = 15   65   63
    54   32   78
```

I don't even know how to start because, for example, the dimension of B should be determined dynamically (I think)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am not not familiar with calling fortran programs from R. One thing is that your compiler may not be handling pointer returned from functions, Try allocatable in the place of pointer. I wanted to write the answer with allocatable as it is widely supported by recent compilers, then suggest  to use pointer if your compiler supports it. But I did the opposite.

Comment: could you help me with that? I changed `pointer` for `ALLOCATABLE` but I'm not sure how/where to allocate A and B. The R part should be irrelevant, if I were able to make it run in a Fortran program it should work on R

Comment: change only the pointer to allocatable in the declaration of B, both in the subroutine and in the calling program. And nothing else.

Comment: I get the same error :(. There is no need to allocate A or something like that?

Comment: I am turning my previous answer into a full program

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm learning a lot today!

Comment: Makes sense. I will do my best to clean up this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
function extractB(A) result(B)
    integer, dimension(:,:), intent(in) :: A
    integer, dimension(:,:), pointer :: B
    integer :: nrowB, i, pos

    nrowB = count( A(:,2)==56)
    allocate( B(nrowB, size(A,2)-1 ) )
    pos = 1
    do i = 1, size(A,1)
        if(A(i,2)==56)then
            B(pos,1) = A(i,1)
            B(pos,2:) = A(i,3:)
            pos = pos+1
        end if
    end do
end function extractB
```

That you call like

```
B = extractB(A)
```

with B defined like:

```
integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: B
```

I assumed integer for your arrays. If your compiler implement pointer as return value, you can used pointers in the place of allocatable.

====adding a full program ====

```
module extract
contains

    subroutine testExtract(A, B)
        double precision, dimension(:,:), intent(in)           :: A
        double precision, dimension(:,:), intent(out), allocatable :: B

        B = extractB(A)


    end subroutine testExtract


    function extractB(A) result(B)
        double precision, dimension(:,:), intent(in) :: A
        double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: B
        integer :: nrowB, i, pos

        nrowB = count( A(:,2)==56)
        allocate( B(nrowB, size(A,2)-1 ) )
        pos = 1
        do i = 1, size(A,1)
            if(A(i,2)==56)then
                B(pos,1) = A(i,1)
                B(pos,2:) = A(i,3:)
                pos = pos+1
            end if
        end do
    end function extractB
end module extract

program test
    use extract
    integer, parameter :: n = 3
    integer, parameter :: m = 4
    double precision, dimension(3,4) :: A
    double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: B


    A(1,:) = [11,   22,   43,   55]
    A(2,:) = [15,   56,   65,   63]
    A(3,:) = [54,   56,   32,   78]

    print*, 'A :'
    print*, int(A)

    !B = extractB(A)
    call testExtract(A, B)
    print*, 'B'
    print*, int(B)

end program
```

Comment: Thanks @innoSPG. I updated my question with the problem I have when trying to implement your solution. My fortran compiler is gfortran running in Ubuntu. Thanks a lot!

Comment: if I change the line that calls the function to `CALL testExtract(A, B)` the program does not compiles. One limitation that I have with R is that I have to call subrutines instead of use functions. The error is `test.f90:(.text+0x531): undefined reference to `extractb_'` Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I am not very familiar with writing interfaces inside a subroutine, so I added a small module for that. In that case, it might be simple to copy the body of the function into the subroutine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will write an R follow up question. The fortran part is working as a charm. Thanks again!

Comment: my follow-up question, in case you are curious http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596166/call-fortran-subroutine-with-allocatables-in-r

Answer (score 2):

A loop is clearly a good way to go, but if you want concise, then

```
integer, dimension(N,M) :: A
integer, allocatable :: B(:,:)
integer i

A = ...

B = A(PACK([(i,i=1,SIZE(A,1))],A(:,2)==56),[1,(i,i=3,SIZE(A,2))])
```

I should explain this as there are a number of silly things being done here.  First note that `[..]` is an array constructor, and `[(..)]` is an array constructor with an implied-do.

So `[(i,i=1,SIZE(A,1))]` creates an array with values `1, ..., N` and `[1,(i,i=3,SIZE(A,2))]` an array with values `1, 3, ..., M`.  These form the indexes for the rows and columns of A missing out the second column.  The `PACK` part selects those indexes for rows matching the mask condition `A(:,2)==56`.

Finally, we use vector subscripting to select the suitable rows with the restricted columns.

The only real reason for doing this is to benefit from automatic allocation of `B`.  And that's very marginal.

Don't do this in real code without good documentation.

Comment: Is there any difference in speed of this compared with a loop?

Comment: It's unlikely to be faster, and could be slower, but I've no idea on specifics.  I'd be more worried, though, about array temporaries, especially when you get to much larger matrices.

Comment: The main issue will be larger arrays! I recently increase the size of arrays in a working code and I had a hard time solving a problem related to the temporary arrays. A call to fortran reshape started to crash. To solve the problem, I had to do the reshape by loop. I suspected the size of temporary arrays to be limited because I have plenty of RAM. I will go back to the problem when I have some time.

Comment: The only way to really see how bad this solution is is to try it.  You may find that there is very little, beyond the constructed index arrays, in the way of additional memory required.