# Call FORTRAN subroutine with allocatables in R?

Tags: r, fortran

This is a follow-up question to [my previous Fortran question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592568/subset-array-with-fortran-given-a-condition?noredirect=1#31593363).

I have a working Fortran program that has a subroutine that filters an array. This is the program:

```
program test
    integer, parameter :: n = 3
    integer, parameter :: m = 4
    double precision, dimension(n,m) :: A
    double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: B


    A(1,:) = [11,   22,   43,   55]
    A(2,:) = [15,   56,   65,   63]
    A(3,:) = [54,   56,   32,   78]

    print*, 'A :'
    print*, int(A)

    CALL extractB(A, B)
    print*, 'B'
    print*, int(B)

contains

    subroutine extractB(A, B) 
        implicit none
        double precision, dimension(:,:), intent(in) :: A
        double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: B
        integer :: nrowB, i, pos
        nrowB = count( A(:,2)==56)
        allocate( B(nrowB, size(A,2)-1 ) )
        pos = 1
        do i = 1, size(A,1)
            if(A(i,2)==56)then
                B(pos,1) = A(i,1)
                B(pos,2:) = A(i,3:)
                pos = pos+1
            end if
        end do
    end subroutine extractB
end program
```

The program compiles, runs, and it does what it has to do very well.

I want to call the `extractB` subroutine with R. I have asked [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395435/use-fortran-subroutine-in-r-undefined-symbol) and found was able to make them work, but this one is somehow different and not working.

My fortran subrutine is in the mytest.f90 file and has this code:

```
subroutine extractB(A, B)
implicit none
    double precision, dimension(:,:), intent(in) :: A
    double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: B
    integer :: nrowB, i, pos
    nrowB = count( A(:,2)==56)
    allocate( B(nrowB, size(A,2)-1 ) )
    pos = 1
    do i = 1, size(A,1)
        if(A(i,2)==56)then
            B(pos,1) = A(i,1)
            B(pos,2:) = A(i,3:)
            pos = pos+1
        end if
    end do
end subroutine extractB
```

I compile it in R and load the library with these commands:

```
system("R CMD SHLIB ./Fortran/mytest.f90") 
dyn.load("./Fortran/mytest.so")
```

Then, in R, i create and pass a data frame to the subroutine

A = data.frame(c(11,15,54), c(22,56,56), c(43,65,32), c(55,63,78))
   X<-.Fortran("extractB", A = unlist(A), B = numeric(6))

After that R crashes

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address (nil), cause 'unknown'

Traceback:
 1: .Fortran("extractB", A = unlist(A), B = numeric(6))

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

If I change the subroutine by removing setting the dimensions by hand:

```
subroutine extract(A, B)
implicit none
    double precision, dimension(3,4), intent(in) :: A
    double precision, dimension(2,3)             :: B
    integer :: i, pos
    pos = 1
    do i = 1, size(A,1)
        if(A(i,2)==56)then
            B(pos,1) = A(i,1)
            B(pos,2:) = A(i,3:)
            pos = pos+1
        end if
    end do
end subroutine extract
```

recompile the library, and reload it. I can run

X<-.Fortran("extract", A = unlist(A), B = numeric(6))

dim(X$A) <- dim(A)
dim(X$B) <- c(2,3)

and get what I want

```
> X
$A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   11   22   43   55
[2,]   15   56   65   63
[3,]   54   56   32   78

$B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   15   65   63
[2,]   54   32   78
```

Any way of fixing this?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: No, this will not work or only after very complicated hacks. You would have to teach R how to understand Fortran allocatable array descriptors. Just forget allocatable arguments when doing interoperability with some other language.

Answer (score 0):

Though, as Vladimir F pointed out, this will not work with allocatables like this, you can allocate memory, that can be used by another language in Fortran. But you should use the pointer attribute in that case. However, you will not be able to make use of assumed shape arrays either. Instead of inferring the size of A, you should pass it in explicitly.

If you are willing to change the interface for this, you can get your functionality with something along these lines, ([see also M. S. B.s answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9680050/577108)):

```
subroutine extractB(A_ptr, lenX, lenY, B_ptr, nrowB) bind(c,name=extractB)
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    type(c_ptr), value :: A_ptr
    integer(kind=c_int), value :: lenX, lenY
    type(c_ptr) :: B_ptr
    integer(kind=c_int) :: nrowB

    real(kind=c_double), pointer :: A(:,:)
    real(kind=c_double), pointer :: B(:,:)
    integer :: i, pos

    c_f_pointer(A_ptr, A, [lenX, lenY])
    nrowB = count( A(:,2)==56)
    allocate( B(nrowB, size(A,2)-1 ) )
    !...
    B_ptr = c_loc(B)
end subroutine extractB
```

Comment: @DongdongKong I don't know much about R. It looks like, if you want to allocate stuff for R, you'd need to encapsulate some C-Routines and call them in Fortran: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Allocating-storage. Calling this stuff is described in https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Interface-functions-_002eCall-and-_002eExternal. The solution to allocation outside of R is probably to have a C-wrapper that takes care of the type conversion stuff, and call the Fortran routine inside of that.